# Move Tag Manager preview mode to the top of the page?

Tags: tag-manager

I want to move the Tag Manager preview mode to the top of the page. I am testing in Google Developer Tools on a mobile device, but the preview mode is in front of some buttons I want to test. Can I move it?

Comment: I don't think you can affect the position of the preview pane. What you could do is add some space to the bottom of your page so that you can still access the buttons while you test. Not ideal, I know, but it would work.